# what is the cause of this error in swift? : script error -54. Couldn't get error text because of error -1700

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, applescript

I have an AppleScript on my desktop getting two inputs and I need to run it in swift.
When I run this command in the terminal, I get what I want:

```
osascript /Users/faranegar/Desktop/sms.scpt +12345678901 "my text message"
```

so I want to run exactly the above command in my swift code so I wrote this code:

```
// Create a Task instance
let task = Process()

// Set the task parameters
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
task.arguments = ["osascript","/Users/faranegar/Desktop/sms.scpt","+12345678901" ,"\"my text message\""]
// Create a Pipe and make the task
// put all the output there
let pipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe

// Launch the task
task.launch()

// Get the data
let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

print(output!)
```

But unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
[Error] /Users/faranegar/Desktop/sms.scpt: script error -54. Couldn't get error text because of error -1700.
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

By the way, this is my AppleScript:

```
on run {targetBuddyPhone, targetMessage}
    tell application "Messages"
    set targetService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
    set targetBuddy to buddy targetBuddyPhone of targetService
    send targetMessage to targetBuddy
 end tell

end run
```

Comment: Looking at this, it seems like you've specified `osascript` twice: once in the launch path and again in the arguments (effectively "/usr/bin/osascript osascript /Users/faranegar..."). Remove it from the arguments list and see if that fixes things. You could also use NSAppleScript to run this rather than a shell task; not sure if that's worth the refactor.

Comment: @TedWrigley yeah you're right. But after changing my code to task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env" , I am still getting an error

Comment: Why would you call usr/bin/env to run an AppleScript? Support is built in. Construct the script as a string and run it. Or use NSAppleScript. Or use the Bridge.

Answer (score 0):

I would just set the command to run `env` so you'll just call the `osascript` found in the user's path:

I tried this and it worked for me.

this is the Apple Script:

```appleScript
on run {targetBuddyPhone, targetMessage}
   "Target Buddy Phone:" & targetBuddyPhone & " - Target Message:" & targetMessage
end run
```

And this is the Full swift script:

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift
import Foundation

let myCommand = Process()
let pipe = Pipe()
if #available(OSX 13, *) {
  myCommand.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/env")
} else {
  myCommand.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
}
myCommand.arguments = ["osascript", "./script.scpt","+12345678901" ,"\"my text message\""]
myCommand.standardOutput = pipe
do {
  if #available(OSX 13, *) {
    try myCommand.run()
  } else {
    myCommand.launch()
  }
  myCommand.waitUntilExit()
  let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
  if let output = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    print(output)
  }
}
```

And when I ran the script I got:

```
Target Buddy Phone:+12345678901 - Target Message:"my text message"
```

Let me know if that worked, I wrote an intro to Swift Scripting(https://rderik.com/blog/using-swift-for-scripting/) you might find useful.

**UPDATE**
Created the full swift script and a test AppleScript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But after pasting this block of code in Xcode 10.3, I am facing these errors:

>Use of unresolved identifier 'myCommand'; did you mean 'doCommand'?
>Use of unresolved identifier 'pmset'
>Value of type '(Selector) -> Void' has no member 'executableURL'

Comment: I tried this : 


let ls = Process()
  ls.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/env")
  ls.arguments = ["osascript","/Users/faranegar/Desktop/sms.scpt" ,"+989194774880" ,"\"hi\""]
  do{
   try ls.run()
  } catch { }


 but still getting script error -54.

Comment: I forgot to declare: `myCommand`. It should be `let myCommand = Process()` at the beginning.

Comment: @HamidrezaShokouhi I updated the answer, so you can easily copy and paste both scripts and test them. They should work

Comment: thanks. I tried your code and the code is ok but I keep getting this error : /Users/faranegar/Desktop/sms.scpt: script error -54.  Couldn't get error text because of error -1700.